# Programmatically signing a document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am using the embedded DocuSign envelope signing process using multiple captive recipients.

In our signing process multiple users have to sign the document and after they are done the company representative receives an email asking for his signature.

I would like to automatically (programmaticaly) sign the envelope on behalf of the last signer so he wouldn't have to manually e-sign lots of documents per day.

Is there any method in the DocuSign SOAP API that would help me accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocuSign Can the documents be signed automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932574/docusign-can-the-documents-be-signed-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to automatically apply signatures to documents using the DocuSign SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

The signing of document(s) whether electronically or not still needs to be done by a human.  If that part is automated it pretty much defeats the purpose.  Even if eventually there is a way to automate the signing process, I would imagine there still has to be at least *some* sort of interaction or "kick-off" of that process by a human, but only time will tell for that.

Comment: Not true. If the human controls the signing process, then it's fine for a computer system to act as an agent and sign on behalf of the human.