# DocuSign Can the documents be signed automatically

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a solution for a client. The client runs a university and wants a system using which they can send the bulk letters that will contain the Marks / Grading to the Parents/Guardians. The letters will have to be signed by the Dean of the university (single user).

Will the user (Dean) have to go in DocuSign and sign each letter individually or is there a way to do it automatically? I am planning to use SOAP API with C# for this.

Comment: Same question was already asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328416/programmatically-signing-a-document

Answer (score 4):

It is not-uncommon to programmatically sign documents. If the business process is properly set up, then it is legal too.

Your use case is a perfect example of a valid use case for auto-signing.

The [DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/signature-appliance) supports auto-signing and that's a common use case for it. For example, the product is often used to automatically sign invoices.

[Developer center for the DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/signature-appliance)

Answer (score 0):

Signing is an explicit activity by the recipient. There is no way to programmatically sign a document.